# Does Uncanny Dodge allow me to retain my Dodge bonus to AC when flat footed?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature

Does the *Uncanny Dodge* class feature (such as below) allow a character to retain any dodge bonus to AC that they have whilst flat-footed?

---

Relevant quotes:

> **Uncanny Dodge (Ex)**
>   ... He retains his Dexterity bonus to AC (if any) even if he is caught flat-footed ...
>
> **Dodge Bonus**
>   Any situation or effect (except wearing armor) that negates a character's Dexterity bonus also negates any dodge bonuses the character may have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Uncanny dodge makes being flat-footed no longer a “situation or effect [...] that negates [the] character’s Dexterity bonus,” so you also no longer lose your dodge bonus.

Answer (score 2):

Dodge (feat) said D&D 3.5

> **Benefit:** During your action, you designate an opponent and receive a +1 dodge bonus to Armor Class against attacks from that opponent

You haven't got your action, so you could not designate an opponent, so you don't have the +1 dodge bonus; but bonus from martial arts dodge (I don't remember exactly) is kept.

Edit : if you had an action and declared the dodge on the bad guy, you retain your dodge bonus from the dodge feat ;)

Comment: That’s a great point, but you can be flat-footed in situations other than before your first turn, and you can get dodge bonuses to AC from things other than the Dodge feat.

Comment: This is about **uncanny** dodge.